# SQL -- There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql-server

Not too experienced with SQL

See my error:
[image]

I have the following Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHORS (
  AuthorID INT NOT NULL,
  AuthorFirstName VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  AuthorLastName VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  AuthorCountry VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PUBLISHERS_PublisherID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID, PUBLISHERS_PublisherID),
  INDEX fk_AUTHORS_PUBLISHERS1_idx (PUBLISHERS_PublisherID ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_AUTHORS_PUBLISHERS1
  FOREIGN KEY (PUBLISHERS_PublisherID)
  REFERENCES dbo.PUBLISHERS (PublisherID))
```

That table has no errors, but the following table is where the error occurs at `REFERENCES AUTHORS (AuthorID)`

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKS (
ISBN INT NOT NULL,
  SeriesName VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  Title VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  AuthorID INT NULL,
  PublicationDate DATE NULL,
  Publisher VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  AUTHORS_AuthorID INT NOT NULL,
  Series_SeriesName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  Series_AuthorID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ISBN, AUTHORS_AuthorID, Series_SeriesName, Series_AuthorID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_BOOKS_AUTHORS1
    FOREIGN KEY (AUTHORS_AuthorID)
    REFERENCES AUTHORS (AuthorID)
  CONSTRAINT fk_BOOKS_Series1
    FOREIGN KEY (Series_SeriesName , Series_AuthorID)
    REFERENCES SERIES (SeriesName , AuthorID))
```

I'm sure I need to fix something or add something but I'm not sure what, thanks.

See my ERD Diagram

[image: ERD]

Comment: the primary key of `AUTHORS` is a composite one using `AuthorID` and `PUBLISHERS_PublisherID`. You can't later have a foreign key that references just one of those columns, every foreign key must reference the while primary key of the referenced table

Comment: why is the PK of authors a composite one? you would expect authorid to be the PK on its own. there should be a separate table linking authors to 0,1, or many publishers.

Comment: I'm not sure why, I just reversed engineered in my sql workbench see my erd diagram https://imgur.com/a/9MbLs

Comment: You are referencing a foreign key in Books table while referencing AuthorID in Authors table.

Comment: Thanks, ended up just redoing the ERD in another program, that makes up the tables as you draw the diagram. Then I was able to see my simple mistake, ended up having to fix multiple tables as well. Everyones answer makes sense too, thank you so much. Such a simple mistake but now I learned.